# Como comparar correctamente el metodo getPassword de un jPasswordField

Tags: java, comparaciones, contraseña

Buenas tardes,

Resulta que hoy estaba realizando un formulario de login con java por primera vez.

Para recuperar la contraseña iba a utilizar el método getText(), pero he visto que esta en desuso ya que devuelve un String y eso haría que se quedase en memoria durante mucho tiempo por lo que es una vulnerabilidad. En su lugar he visto que existe el método getPassword() que devuelve un array de caracteres.

El problema lo tengo cuando quiero comparar el array que devuelve, con una contraseña que recupero de la base de datos en tipo String.

Las dudas son las siguiente:

- Es correcto recuperar la contraseña de la base de datos como String? Tendría la misma vulnerabilidad que si recupero la contraseña con el metodo getText(), no?
- Como haríais vosotros para comparar estas dos contraseñas evitando la vulnerabilidad mencionada? ?

Espero no haberos aburrido con este texto.
Saludos,
Rubén.

Comment: Hola Ruben. Lastimosamente, este tipo de preguntas tan abiertas no se pueden realizar en el sitio. Sin embargo, puedes acceder al [salón de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde esas preguntas son bienvenidas puesto que el chat es más informal y las personas cuentan sus opiniones sobre diversos temas. Solo haz click en el enlace de este comentario. Si no tienes reputación suficiente, solo tienes que esperar y seguir participando en el sitio.